Background color gets cut off on horizontal scroll
I have a problem where containers that have min/max width set have a cut off background color and border after horizontal scrolling.
Please ignore a lot of containers, it's just a simplified version of a React component tree that I'm dealing with:


.page-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bg-wrapper {
  background-color: wheat;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.bg-green {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="bg-wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="bg-red">
              <div class="box">
                <header>
                  <h1>Test</h1>
                  <h3>Test</h3>
                </header>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bg-green">
              <div class="box">
                <h1>Content</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Here's how it looks after scrolling horizontally:

And this is what I expect:

The only fix I have in mind is adding display: inline-block to .content but that introduces other issues so I wouldn't want that.

It's working fine in stackoverflow preview feature.

it does with a default window width but as soon as you make it smaller the bug pops up

As per the above comment I got your point and you were correct I was able to reproduce the problem now. It is caused by the way nested elements with min-width and max-width are sized within their containing elements.
So I tried it on jsfiddle and fixed it.

Below is the code for the same :


.page-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bg-wrapper {
  background-color: wheat;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.bg-green {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.bg-green, .bg-red {
  min-width: max-content;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Added box-sizing */
}
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="bg-wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="bg-red">
              <div class="box">
                <header>
                  <h1>Test</h1>
                  <h3>Test</h3>
                </header>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bg-green">
              <div class="box">
                <h1>Content</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Zoomed at 100% Output :

Zoomed at 300% Output :


Other options :

Use Flexbox or Grid Layout

Using box-sizing: tag border-box

Setting a Specific Width (like width: 400px;)


